# How can I correct loud audio with noisy high peaks?

Tags: audio-recording, audio, audacity, production-audio

Accidentally, the song was recorder without hardware filter, and it become too loud and distorted on high peaks (you can see and hear noise on high peaks):

[image]
example audio file is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xmhEGcXt9fYk4fTuyZPRkDUXCcS4Kh-R).

Is that possible to clear and correct as, those noisy distortions were made a bit better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Izotope RX Advanced De-Clipper is really your only chance at saving this.

Comment: how did you go?